# WordPress Api request error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:700)

Tags: python, wordpress, api, ssl

I am trying to use api post request with Python to post some text in WordPress by using instructions from this site: [WordPress APi](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

My Code:

```
articleCategories=['Test1']
client = Client('https://wordpress.site.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username','password')
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'Test1'
post.content = 'This is a test'
post.terms_names = {'category':articleCategories}
post.post_status = 'publish'
client.call(NewPost(post))
```

When i am running it i am receiving the following error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:700)
```

Can you help with it?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with the below WooCommerce api, the easiest way around this is to just use http:// instead of https:// in the client URL. I imagine this same solution may work for the api you are using.

You might consider using [this](https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/) WooCommerce api that you may find a bit more up-to-date and easier to use.